# No such property error in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I've been struggling with Gradle transform api and bytecode manipulation, I'm trying to change the class file in jars dynamically via ASM, and I met some problems when giving output to jars. I encountered this error, but I don't know which part is wrong.

By the way, if any of you ever done something like this before, I'm very willing to listen your understanding of transform api, how it give outputs to class files, especially jars.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7lta.jpg)

Comment: You know screenshots are a horrible way to share code yeah? Paste it into the question, select it, and Mark it as code using the toolbar (it prefixes it with 4 spaces)

Comment: thanks...I didnt know that and found it troublesome everytime I want to post a question...

Comment: Can be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Please refrain from using txtspk here - expanding "idk" and "plz" is not particularly arduous work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable called `tempFile` and you trying to use `tmpFile` on line 110